# Form in html/php receving and sending

Tags: php, forms, post

I want to create an application in `php`. It connects with my database, takes all information for selected categories (autor, date, begging of his book) and displays a button. When clicked, it redirects user to another website and shows all the information about the selected author. So for example you open my website:

> Author: blablabla
> Data: blablabla
> Begging: blablabla
>
> BUTTON HERE CLICK ME TO GET MORE INFO
>
> Author: 2
> Data: 2/2/20015
> begging: 222222
>
> BUTTON HERE CLICK ME TO GET MORE INFO

It looked quite easy. I connected to the database, made loop to show all selected data about all authors, created forms with names, like id of author and I want to read name in another file and show all data about this specific author. My `xampp` says it doesn't recognize the id's, but when I echo it on screen, it looks just fine.

My engine file:

```
$polaczenie = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die("Brak polaczenia z serwerem bazy danych: " . mysql_error());
$baza = mysql_select_db('news',$polaczenie) or exit("Nie mozna wybrac bazy:" . mysql_error());

$sql = "Select id,autor,tytul,data,wstep from informacje;";

$zap1 = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Blad zapytania:' . mysql_error());
echo "Oto spis książek:";
$i=0;
while ($rekord = mysql_fetch_assoc($zap1)) 
{
  $i++
  ?>
    <h2><?php echo "Tytuł:".$rekord["tytul"];?></h2>
    <h3><?php echo "Autor:".$rekord["autor"]." Data:".$rekord["data"];?></h3>
    <?php echo "Wstep:".$rekord["wstep"];?>
    <?php echo "Idik:".$i;?>
    <form Name ="formularz" Method ="POST" ACTION = "CzytajWiecej.php">
      <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "<?php$i;?>" VALUE = "O tym chce poczytać więcej!">
    </form>
  <?php
}
```

My CzytajWiecej.php file:

```
<?php

  echo $_POST['1'];
```

Comment: Well... I know it might seems quite stupid for someone but you could just write whats wrong with me instead of votting me down...

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Haha it might look funny but i forgot to write echo here:

```
 <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "<?php$i;?>"
```

Thanks for your feedback ,maybe it'll help someone someday -_-